# Can I reformat rich-text-formatted strings when I write them to a file from Python?

Tags: python, string, rtf

In my current project, I am importing rich-text-formatted files from my 2015 Journals, then snipping around the dates and uploading them into various other formats.  I have created a csv and a sql database with this list of rich-text-formatted strings (the daily entries in my journal, without dates).

Ultimately, I think I will just forgo formatting and import the original document as a .txt file.  Still, however, I'm curious--is there a good way to re-format these strings if I were to bring them to another program that can read rich-text?

```
with open("chonky-dates-2015.rtf", "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    txt = file.read()
    # print(txt)


    # FIND 2015
    date_end_array = txt.split("2015")

    # Remove the date from the end of 2015 (deletes everything up to the rtf that begins every date)
    dateless_array = [item.rsplit("\\f0\\b", 1)[0] for item in date_end_array]

    # # Make a CSV out of dateless_array
    # data = pd.Series(dateless_array)
    # data.to_csv("days-of-2015")

    # # Make an RTF
    with open("new-chonky.txt", "w") as newdoc:
        for item in dateless_array:
            newdoc.write(item)
```

Comment: You may be able to use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/index.html) to convert to any of a number of formats that allow for easier (?) parsing than just the split. Now the strings could be something like html, or maybe its the start of rewapping them into rtf again. pandoc could let you decide what format you want these strings in. (or no format at all if you don't care about bold, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

You need a rich-text parser for Python. Luckily, there are many already implemented.

Take a look at [rtfcre](https://github.com/sammdot/rtfcre) :D